# GWT maven app not starting

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

I created a GWT app project using the gwt-maven-plugin and added the same to eclipse. Tried running it from eclipse (as a web application) however got the following errors ([screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/214/gwterrors.png/)). Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Would like to mention that the app builds fine and when i manually deploy that war file in tomcat, the app works as expected. However running from eclipse causes issues.

Cross posted [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/568582/GWT/GWT-maven-app-not-starting)

Comment: Have you tried to google your problem? Here's [Google link](http://www.google.com.ua/webhp?rlz=1C1ASUT_enUA391UA391&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=ru&rlz=1C1ASUT_enUA391UA391&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=greetingserviceasync%20cannot%20be%20resolved%20to%20a%20type&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=607a98a269108a8b&ix=seb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=681)  and [Possible answer](http://groups.google.com/group/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/browse_thread/thread/e34a24e9de5c7e41?pli=1).

Comment: Thank you, that link solved my problem. I did google search but not this specific 'greetingserviceasync cannot be resolved to a type'. my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add target/generated-sources/gwt to the Eclipse build path. This is not done automatically, unfortunately. This solved my problem. [Source](http://groups.google.com/group/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/browse_thread/thread/e34a24e9de5c7e41?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a monstrous piece of pretentiously well-designed platform.

Eclipse native dependency is osgi, not Maven. Maven and eclipse integration have lots of room for improvement - but how much more Eclipse is willing to accommodate the efficiency of Maven is questionable because OSGI is their own backyard. That does not explain very much your problem - but that is the fundamental cause of your problem because the disconnect makes it hard for any non-OSGI framework to give the end-programmer a satisfactory programming experience.

This happens frequently when you create a project and then turn it into MAven. Or you create a Maven project and turn it into a web project. Is it Maven's fault? Of course it is - because Eclipse does not make it easier for non-OSGI to play with it. Eclipse does not make it easier for Ant to auto-build Eclipse projects. And even though Eclipse has no means to allow build scripts that you could submit to your OS scheduler, it does not make it easy for Ant or Maven.

Perhaps, eclipse should abandon OSGI and just work with Maven hand-in-hand to jointly improve our situation. OTOH, Maven is a framework where their creators would like it to be a generic build/dependency system that is as generic as possible and not locked into Eclipse. On the other other other hand, Eclipse wants to be as "generic" a development platform as possible and not get locked into Maven. So the two perceptions striving for generic orthogonality is completely non-orthogonally aligned. Eclipse needs to rethink their raison d'etre.

So, what you have to do is, search for the source folders that got neglected and right click on it to use them as source in the buildpath properties. Inspect your web.xml to ensure that the greetings rpc remote service is listed.

Comment: OK, this response risks a meltdown of down votes but any of you have not sinned by having to work hoops around it - cast the first stone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of your problem, however I know what to do to make what what you need.
Google gives two peaces of information on how to tie eclipse GWT and maven:

1. http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_with_maven
2. http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/05/gwt-and-maven-playing-nicely-together.html

Follow the instructions from this links, they are very simple and you will get what you need.
That is you will be able to run project from eclipse in development mode.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the path was already added to the build path. Changing compiler-plugin source/target from 1.5 to 1.6 fixed my problems:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```